# CSS: background color is not applied when horizontal scrollbar is shown

Tags: html, css

This markup

```
<div style="background-color: red;">
    abcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcd
</div>
```

works properly when the browser window is wide enough, but when I make it smaller to see the horizontal scrollbar, the background color is applied only to the visible part:

[image]

Can this be fixed?

Comment: In what browser does this problem occur? Do you have some more code? Can this problem be replicated in jsFiddle? Also, you really shouldn't use inline styles. Use a separate CSS file for styling purposes.

Comment: @Sven, Chromium and Firefox. That's all the code needed to replicate. Inline styles are for the sake of SO, not used in production

Comment: @Fluffy : I think you should set the `overflow` property of the div to `auto`

Comment: What are all the other styles on this div and those containing it? Show us those. Specifically, how are you creating the overflow.

Comment: Why are you resorting to position:absolute? I'm sure you can get the normal behavior without that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try it with `position:absolute;`

```
<div style="background-color: red; position:absolute;">
    abcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcd
</div>
```

**EDIT :**

or with `display:inline;`

```
<div style="background-color: red; display:inline;">
    abcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcd
</div>
```

Comment: This does actually work, but is there a way to avoid position absolute? It would ruin the rest of the page.

Comment: @Fluffy Try relative or static position

Comment: Relative - doesn't work. Static is the default so it didn't work to begin with

Comment: @Fluffy u can try `display:inline-block;` as alternative

Answer (score 1):

Try one way is with `position:absolute`.

```
<div style="background-color: red;position: absolute;">
    <p>abcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcd</p>
</div>
```

Other way is with some `width`.

```
<div style="background-color: red;width: 500px">
    <p>abcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcd</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
<div>
<p style="background-color:red;">
abcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcd
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Inline styles are bad practice and should be avoided at all cost.

Comment: I was just trying to provide an answer in the format @Fluffy provided the question, for simplicity.

Comment: This did not help. Still the same behavior.

Answer (score -2):

```
<div style="background-color: red;display:table">
    abcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcd
</div>
```

No IE7 support though.

Comment: Does not expand to full window size in wide browser.

Comment: It was enough to put a width:100% on it.